# drupal openlayers popup only shows 1 item

Tags: drupal-7, openlayers

I've added items to a map. All is OK except when I have multiple items with the same geolocation, they should be all listed in the popup and instead only 1 item now shows. I've tried this with 2 items that have identical geolocations. Only one shows up in the popup when I click the marker. If I unpublish that item, the other one then shows up. But for some reason, only one can show up at a time. I've looked in code to see if both are there, but only one is there.

Can't figure out what is wrong. I've made sure my openlayer data layer in views allows all items to be shown and isn't limiting things.

Anyone have an idea why this is?

Thanks.
James

Answer (score 1):

You have to use marker cluster behavior for this. Under openlayers -> maps -> your map -> behaviors, there is clustering feature.

Comment: Clustering works, but the popup still only shows one item (even though now there's `(2)` showing after the popup). Even tried with grouping results, doesn't work either, only change is that now it says `(1)` after the popup.